# How can I bind complex object to a field in Kendo Scheduler

Tags: javascript, web, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I would like to add share functionality to Kendo Scheduler and in order to do this I would like the share field to be a complex object not just a simple strin for example.

So what I want to do is the following:

```
    schema: {
        model: {
            id: "taskId",
            fields: {
                taskId: { from: "Id", type: "number" },
                title: { from: "Title", defaultValue: "No title", validation: { required: true }                                },
                start: { type: "date", from: "StartsOn" },
                end: { type: "date", from: "EndsOn" },


                Share:[
                    {
                        user: { from: "users", defaultValue: 1 }, //users is a resource
                        right: { from: "rights", defaultValue: 1 },
                    }],
            }
        }
```

can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is use schema: {parse: }.

According to the api doc for kendo

> parse
>
> Executed before the server response is used. Use it to preprocess or
>   parse the server response.

I've used it in coffeescript like so:

```
schema:
  model:
    id: "id"
    fields:
      id: editable: false
      title: from: "name"
  parse: (response)->
    $(response).each ->
      this.share = [{user: this.users, right: this.rights}]
    return response
```